# How to reduce the execution time of this script?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, profiling

For more than a week I have been trying to optimize my scripts for MySQL queries. Finally I decided to install Xdebug on my production environment and I found some of the results funny:

1. Using the MySQL slow query it doesn't return me a higher work on the server. So it means my queries are not slow at all. Perhaps this is because I don't have many data as yet.
2. Installing the memcached reduced some of my PHP execution time, from 5 mins to 1 or 2 mins sometimes, but some issues came on. Memcached does not return a new entry for my users. Obviously I'm taking datas from memory about 1 minute later of database. So anyway I decide I wouldn't implement memcached for now. There are not many users to work with some like that. Anyway time speed goes slowly.

That's the scenery for my server app. But a few days ago I implemented a new module for security reasons, creating a encrypted key for all my objects on my app. I implemented the datacrypt class for that, it works perfectly on my development enviroment on my laptop obviously.

**Why did I came to ask for help?** 
Looking into the Xdebug profiling using winCachegrind I found that the instantiation of datacrypt takes 37,218ms for execution, some of my files show 10 or 15 rows and each of those rows makes and encrypted key on the fly.

The high use of datacrypt class is a problem. It is used in every script file. So I need to get a new fast class to make an encrypted hash to use in my app.

Can anyone could recommend me one? Or what can I do to make datacrypt run faster?

If you want to take a look at my scripts let me know.

```
    <div class="property-holder">
<?php

    require BASE_DIR.'/controller/listing.php';

    if(is_array($rows)){
        echo $nav;  
    ?>
<div id="properties-listing" class="content center container-wraps">
<?php
        //$crypt =  new datacrypt();
        foreach($rows as $row){

                //$pkey = $crypt->encrypt($row['property_type'].'-'.$row['property_id'].'-'.$row['broker_id'].'-'.$row['company_id']);
                    if($row[property_type] == 'development'){
                    $picture = (( $row['dev_logo']!='')?'<img class="ui-action" rel="open"  src="'.HOST.'thumbs/80x80/dev/'.$row['dev_logo'].'" />':'<img src="'.HOST.'imgss/noimage.jpg" width="80" height="80" />');
                    }else{
                    $picture = (( $row['image']!='')?'<img class="ui-action" rel="open"  src="'.HOST.'thumbs/80x80/'.$row['property_id'].'/'.$row['image'].'" width="80" height="80" />':'<img src="'.HOST.'imgss/noimage.jpg" width="80" height="80" />');
                    }
                    $prop.=' <div class="listing clearfix shadowbox" id="'.$pkey.'" ref="MLS-'.$row['property_id'].'"  >';
                    $prop.='<div class="listing-photo  left"><a href="#property-view" rel="load-content">'.$picture.'</a></div>';
                    $prop.='<div class="left listing-holder clearfix">';                    
                        $prop.='<h2 class="title"><span class="location"> '.$row['city'].', '.$row['estate'].', '.$row['country'].' </span> '.$row['property_name'].' <em class="company"> ( MLS-'.$row['property_id'].' )</em> '.($_SESSION[company_id]==$row[company_id]?'<span class="company ui-icon ui-icon-heart" ></span>':'').'</h2>';
                        $prop.='<div class="listing-description clearfix"><ul>';

                        $prop.='<div class="threebox left">';
                        $prop.='<li><span>'.T_('Tipo de propiedad').'</span><strong>'.$row['category'].' </strong></li>';   
                        $prop.='<li><span>'.T_('unidad/es disponible').'</span>'.$row['units'].'</li>'; 
                        $prop.='</div>';
                        $prop.='<div class="threebox left">';
                        if((boolean)$row['negotiation']){
                        $prop.='<li>'.T_('precio disponible a').'<strong> '.T_('negociaci&oacute;n').'</strong></li>';  
                        }

                        if((boolean)$row['for_rent'] ){
                                if($row['property_type'] == 'development'){
                                $prop.='<li><span><strong>'.T_('en renta desde:').'</strong></span> $ '.number_format($row['min_rent']).' '.T_('hasta').' '.$row['max_rent'].'</li>';   
                                }else{
                                $prop.='<li><span><strong>'.T_('renta:').'</strong></span> $ '.number_format($row['rent_price']).' '.$row['currency_type'].'</li>'; 
                                }

                            }
                            if((boolean)$row['for_sale'] ){
                                if($row['property_type'] == 'development'){
                                $prop.='<li><span><strong>'.T_('en venta desde:').'</strong></span> $ '.number_format($row['min_sale']).' '.T_('hasta').' '.$row['max_sale'].'</li>';   
                                }else{
                                $prop.='<li><span><strong>'.T_('venta:').'</strong></span>  $ '.number_format($row['sale_price']).' '.$row['currency_type'].'</li>';    
                                }
                            }
                            if((boolean)$row['for_vacational'] ){
                            $prop.='<li><span><strong>'.T_('renta vacacional:').'</strong></span> $ '.number_format($row['min_price']).'  / $ '.number_format($row['mid_price']).' / $ '.number_format($row['hig_price']).' '.$row['currency_type'].'</li>';    
                            }
                            $prop.='<li><span>'.T_('Tipo de propiedad').'</span><strong>'.($row[property_type]=='development'?T_('desarrollo'):$row['category']).' </strong></li>'; 
                            if($row[property_type]=='inventory'){

                            $prop.='<li><strong>'.T_('Pertenece a desarrollo').'</strong></li>';    
                            }

                        $prop.='</div>';
                        $prop.='<div class="threebox left">';
                        $prop.='<li><span>'.T_('Ba&ntilde;os:').'</span><strong> '.$row['bathrooms'].'</strong></li>';  
                        $prop.='<li><span>'.T_('Habitaciones:').'</span> '.$row['bedrooms'].'</li>';    
                        $prop.='</div>';
                        $prop.='</ul></div>';
                    $prop.='</div>';
                    $prop.='<div class="options" >
                            <ul>';
                    $prop.='<li><a rel="open" href="'.HOST.LANG.'/property/?k='.urlencode($pkey).'" title="'.T_('Ver descripcion completa de la propiedad.').'" ><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-contact"></span>'.T_('ver m&aacute;s').'</a></li>';
                    $prop.='<li><a rel="note" href="#" title="'.T_('Agregar nota a esta propiedad, este mensaje es solo entre la empresa que lista la propiedad y tu como broker.').'" ><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-tag"></span>'.T_('nota').'</a></li>';
                    $prop.='<li><a rel="info" href="#" title="'.T_('Ver informacion de la empresa que lista esta propiedad.').'" ><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-contact"></span>'.T_('info').'</a></li>';
                    $prop.='<li><a rel="open" href="'.HOST.LANG.'/pdf/?k='.urlencode($pkey).'" title="'.T_('Descargar presentaci&oacute;n en pdf').'"  title="'.T_('Descargar presentaci&oacute;n en pdf de esta propiedad').'"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"></span>'.T_('PDF').'</a></li>';
                    $prop.='</ul>
                        </div>';
                        /*
                    $prop.='<div class="metadata threebox center shadowbox content darknessbox" >';
                        $prop.='<h3>'.$row[companyname].'</h3>';
                        $prop.='<p>'.$row[companyaddress].' </p>';
                        $prop.=' < '.$row[companyweb].' >  '.$row[companyphone].' </p>';
                        $prop.='<p><strong>'.$row[brokername].'</strong> < '.$row[brokeremail].' >  <br />'.$row[brokerphone].'  &mdash; '.$row[brokermobile].'</p>';
                        $prop.='<em>MLS-'.$row['id'].' </em>: <strong>c. '.$row[commission].'</strong>';
                    $prop.=' </div>'; */
                $prop.=' </div>';
            }
            echo $prop;
    ?>
        </div>

    <?php
        echo $nav;  
    }else{
        message(T_('Wow!, lo sentimos no hay propiedades para mostrar'),'warning');
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Multiple exclamation marks are a sure sign of a diseased mind.

Comment: And your writing is pretty incoherent. I have a hard time grasping what you want.

Comment: sorry i'm not an english speaker! :S

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt anything?

Comment: for security reason, i'm passing via get the id from anythink for edit, transfer, and some other stuff. so i don-t want to use the id. instead using some safe key hash, does you know any good and fast class?

Comment: Security by obscurity is no security at all. Use the real IDs in your URLs and validate that the current user has permission to perform that action on that ID. Simply replacing the IDs with different looking "encrypted" IDs without validating permission is not security.

Comment: i check permission on my files, i begin to use a key encrypted, cause i guess it will increase my security system, if someone wants to make some kind of reverse engine

Comment: by the way, i'm passing three ids encrypted, i know we could pass those joined as a simple string but for error i guess using encryption will be nice and a plus on security. any way first big error of year

Comment: Why are you concatenating so many strings instead of outputting directly? String concatenation in that form is typically more expensive than directly `echo`ing.

Comment: yeah i read about this, i'll keep it in mind, ready added to my todo list. thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for the excesive use of marks, i'm not trying to be offensive. :)

Comment: show the code from the datacrypt if possible?

Comment: it cames at the sour on the quiestion, it's commented

Answer (score 1):

tips: 1- use template to separate the PHP code from the HTML code. 
      2- print  time()  to generate the time before execution and after the execution.

example:

```
  <?

  $start=time();
  some code here 1 ,,,,,,,,
  $after1=time();
  $total1=$after1-$start;
  echo "total time for execution this part:  ".$total1

 ?>
```

Comment: great idea for testing purpose. i'm implemented it, on the whole script